# How to refresh Facebook access token automatically in an iPhone app and Android app?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, facebook

I am developing a product for iPhone and Android for Facebook users. Since "offline_access" permissions had been removed from Facebook Graph API, and the life time of an access token can only extended to 60 days, I want to know if there is a way to refresh access token automatically. Anyone has a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You no need to care about refresh the token, facebook sdk will take care of that automatically

Comment: Thanks! But will it work in both platform? As my app contains some user data, I am worrying if it required user's authorization again it may take a long time to re-import those data.

Comment: I dont know abt Iphone but in android it does

Comment: Well, after the Facebook SDK get the token can the app record it and send it back to the server, so that the server can use the new token to update user's data?

Answer (score 1):

In ios you can extend token using following methods:

```
- (void)extendAccessToken {
    if (_isExtendingAccessToken) {
        return;
    }
    _isExtendingAccessToken = YES;
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"auth.extendSSOAccessToken", @"method", nil];
    [self requestWithParams:params andDelegate:self];
}

//+ * Calls extendAccessToken if shouldExtendAccessToken returns YES.

- (void)extendAccessTokenIfNeeded {



    if ([self shouldExtendAccessToken]) {
        [self extendAccessToken];
    }
}

//  Returns YES if the last time a new token was obtained was over 24 hours ago.

- (BOOL)shouldExtendAccessToken {
        if ([self isSessionValid]){
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:_lastAccessTokenUpdatetoDate:[NSDate date]options:0];

        if (components.hour >= kTokenExtendThreshold) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

as given in this [Link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/4aa2a663b2b735cc736b4177a1947e176d9f4446)

Comment: Thanks for the method? So in this way the app can refresh the access token and it will never expired? 

BTW, can't see the link. :)

Comment: k check again link is now displaying